# How to use dynamic/variable image tag in a Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kustomize

In our project, which also uses Kustomize, our base `deployment.yaml` file looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:IMAGE_TAG # <------------------------------
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Then we use `sed` to replace `IMAGE_TAG` with the version of the image we want to deploy.

Is there a more sophisticated way to do this, rather than editing the text yaml file using `sed`?

Comment: Could this part of the kubernettes documentation help you ? [Use a JSON merge patch to update a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment)

Comment: I am not sure. Have to read it through.

Comment: try `helm` but may be overkill.

Comment: `envsubst < deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a specific transformer for this called the [images transformer](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/images/).
You can keep your deployment as it is, with or without tag:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and then in your kustomization file:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - deployment.yaml

images:
  - name: nginx
    newTag: MYNEWTAG
```

Do keep in mind that this will replace the tag of all the nginx images of all the resources included in your kustomization file. If you need to run multiple versions of nginx you can replace the image name in your deployment by a placeholder and have different entries in the transformer.

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to use an **image tag from an environment variable**, without having to edit files for each different tag. This is useful if your image tag needs to vary without changing version-controlled files.

Standard `kubectl` is enough for this purpose. In short, use a [`configMapGenerator`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#configmapgenerator) with data populated from environment variables. Then add [`replacements`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/replacements/) that refer to this ConfigMap data to replace relevant image tags.

## Example

Continuing with your example `deployment.yaml`, you could have a `kustomization.yaml` file in the same folder that looks like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

# Generate a ConfigMap based on the environment variables in the file `.env`.
configMapGenerator:
  - name: my-config-map
    envs:
      - .env

replacements:
  - source:
      # Replace any matches by the value of environment variable `MY_IMAGE_TAG`.
      kind: ConfigMap
      name: my-config-map
      fieldPath: data.MY_IMAGE_TAG
    targets:
      - select:
          # In each Deployment resource …
          kind: Deployment
        fieldPaths:
          # … match the image of container `nginx` …
          - spec.template.spec.containers.[name=nginx].image
        options:
          # … but replace only the second part (image tag) when split by ":".
          delimiter: ":"
          index: 1

resources:
  - deployment.yaml
```

In the same folder, you need a file `.env` with the environment variable name only (note: just the name, no value assigned):

```
MY_IMAGE_TAG
```

Now `MY_IMAGE_TAG` from the local environment is integrated as the image tag when running `kubectl kustomize`, `kubectl apply --kustomize`, etc.

Demo:

```
MY_IMAGE_TAG=foobar kubectl kustomize .
```

This prints the generated image tag, which is `foobar` as desired:

```yaml
# …
spec:
  # …
  template:
    # …
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx:foobar
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

## Alternatives

Keep the following in mind from the [`configMapGenerator` documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#configmapgenerator):

> **Note:** It's recommended to use the local environment variable population functionality sparingly - an overlay with a patch is often more maintainable. Setting values from the environment may be useful when they cannot easily be predicted, such as a git SHA.

If you are simply looking to share a *fixed* image tag between multiple files, see the already [suggested `images` transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66364133/3881836).

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bug, that will be removed in the next major release. https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/35669

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy solution for those who prefer a CLI.

It's possible to dynamically add an image transformation to your `kustmization` files. Just check in a directory with `kustomization.yaml` and call

```
kustomize edit set image nginx:your_new_tag
```

This will result to the following change in your `kustomization`:

```
images:
- name: nginx
  newTag: your_new_tag
```

The only problem I faced when I tried this solution is that I managed to make it work only with a standalone `kustomize` but not with `kubectl kustomize`. Current version that works for me is `kustomize/v4.5.5`

Answer (score 0):

@evolutics answer is probably "proper" way to do it but if you are customizing only image tag every deployment you could consider putting $IMAGE_TAG variable in `deployment.yaml` and using `envsubst` command.

Example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:$IMAGE_TAG
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

```bash
IMAGE_TAG=my_image_tag envsubst '${IMAGE_TAG}' < deployment.yaml > final_deployment.yaml
```